# How to change markdown item format into task (`[ ]`) on the next line?

Tags: filetype-markdown

When I'm in a markdown file creating a task list, I want it to insert a task list not a list item.

Output:

```markdown
- [ ] **A task** - A task list <Enter>
- Inserted just a dash
```

Would like this:

```markdown
- [ ] **A task** - A task list <Enter>
- [ ] Inserts a task list
```

I already `setlocal fo+=n` and looked into `formatlistpat` but I can't even
seem to insert numbers let alone do what I want to  even if I add to the
default pattern `^\s*\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\s*`.

I know I can probably just hack it with a function or autocomand, just wondering if
there's an option like `indentexpr` or `formatlistpat` that could help me with
this. What is the option that does this behavior to automatically insert stuff?

Comment: `:help fo-table` suggests the `o` option is responsible for automatic insertion, maybe? But that's for comments; I would have though `n` with the right pattern would work, but perhaps it's too specific to numbers.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yea that's for comments, not sure if such a feature even exists. I guess I will just have to make it work with a function or something. I thought the indentexpr did that but turns out that's just for returning the indent levels. Not even sure what is causing that, I went into an account with a minimal vimrc and 2 plugins and it also does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If you have a markdown plugin, patch it or disable it. Some plugins
will have autocommands that will override your settings regardless of what you put in
your *after/markdown.vim*.

```
:help 'com'
:help format-comments
```

In your *ftplugin/markdown.vim* put this.

```
setlocal com=:\-\ [\ ]\ **,b:\-\ [\ ],b:>,b:*,b:+,b:-
```

Tested, works.

```markdown
- This is a normal list.
- This is a normal list.
- [ ] This is a task.
- [ ] This is a task.
- [ ] **Bold** - Bold in a task.
- [ ] **Bold** - Bold in a task.
```

Improvements: Well, if you want to get really picky and don't feel like typing '** - '
after '- [ ] **' then you might want to look into:

- [x] **Ultisnips** - A great plugin for Snippets.
- [x] **Funciton** - Create your own vim function to handle this.
- [x] **Help** - Read more into the `help format-comments`.

P.S I don't think stackoverflow  allows for github task list items.